How to retry the request with Moya/Combine
version: Moya/Combine (15.0.0), CombineExt (1.8.0)
Now I have a need to re -refresh the token when the token expires. After success, I need to re -execute the previous request again. The code is as follows:
private func request(_ target: Target) -> AnyPublisher<Moya.Response ,APIError> {
        let actualRequest = provider.requestPublisher(target)
        return actualRequest.tryMap { response in
            let json = try? response.mapJSON() as? [String: Any]
            if let json, let code = json["code"] as? String {
                if code == "ERR003" {
                    throw APIError.tokenExpired(reason: "token expired")
                }
                if code == "ERR004" {
                    throw APIError.refreshTokenExpired(reason: "login expired")
                }
            }
            return response
        }
        .mapError { error in
            if let error = error as? APIError {
                return error
            }
            if let error = error as? MoyaError {
                return APIError.moyaError(from: error)
            }
            return APIError.unknown
        }
        // `retryWhen` operator is provided by `CombineExt`
        .retryWhen { errorPublisher in
            return errorPublisher.filter { error in
                switch error {
                // When the error type is `tokenexpired`,Only go to re -request
                case .tokenExpired(_):
                    return true
                default: return false
                }
            }
            .setFailureType(to: APIError.self)
            .flatMap { error -> AnyPublisher<Void, APIError> in
                switch error {
                case .tokenExpired(_):
                    // This is my definition of re -refreshing token
                    return LogInManager.share.refreshToken()
                default:
                    return Just(()).setFailureType(to: APIError.self).mapToVoid().eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
       
    }

// The type of error I customized
enum APIError: Error, LocalizedError {
    case unknown, tokenExpired(reason: String), refreshTokenExpired(reason: String), moyaError(from: MoyaError)
    
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .unknown:
            return "Unknown error"
        case .tokenExpired(let reason), .refreshTokenExpired(let reason):
            return reason
        case .moyaError(let from):
            return from.localizedDescription
        }
    }
}

However, after the success of the token, this code did not execute the original request. Does anyone know what happened in my code?

I'm also looking for this, did you find a solution?
